# Python how to unwind CPU limit of 10%?

Tags: python, jupyter

I run my code through Jupyter Notebook. It seems there is a 10% CPU limit for Python (or just Jupyter) .

How can I break this limit ? Can I set this limit self-defined?

Comment: I don't think there is any limiting feature in Jupyter Notebook.  If you are using  a 10 core machine, you are likely using 100% of 1 core.

Comment: @monkut I guess  you are right... So Python can only use 10% of my cpu...Is there a way to use all of my core?

Comment: you can use multiprocessing, if you want to take advantage of more of your processors.